# MySQL query returns different result on second execution

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm not too familiar with MySQL variables but I'm trying to avoid redundant sub selects while calculating these results. The first execution only returns 1 of the correct calculations. The second execution returns all the correct values.

```
SELECT
@discount_code := '*******' AS discount_code,
@sales_revenue := (
    SELECT
        CAST(SUM(total_price) AS UNSIGNED)
    FROM
        shopify_orders
    WHERE
        discount_code = @discount_code
) AS sales_revenue,
@rsp_float := (
    SELECT
        revenue_share_percentage / 100
    FROM
        kpi_data
    WHERE
        CODE = @discount_code
) AS rsp_float,
@marketing_spend := (
    SELECT
        fixed_media_cost + @revenue_share
    FROM
        kpi_data
    WHERE
        CODE = @discount_code
) AS marketing_spend,
@roi_dollars := (
    @sales_revenue - @marketing_spend
) AS roi_dollars,
@revenue_share := (@sales_revenue * @rsp_float) AS revenue_share,
@roi := CAST(
    (@roi_dollars /@marketing_spend) AS DECIMAL (5, 2)
) AS roi,
@mroi := CAST(
    (
        @sales_revenue / @marketing_spend
    ) AS DECIMAL (5, 2)
) AS mroi;
```

First execution:
[image: First execution]

Second execution:
[image: Second execution]

Comment: The order of columns is important, if you are going to use mysql variables this way. You are using `@revenue_share` before it is calculated.

Comment: @ypercube thanks so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of columns is important, if you are going to use mysql variables this way. You are using `@revenue_share` before it is calculated. So, the first time the query runs, `NULL` is used for the calculation of `@marketing_spend`. The second time the query runs, the variable has a value saved from the 1st run.

Additionally, the two subqueries that have `FROM kpi_data` can be combined in one. And you don't really need to use variables. You can get the same results using derived tables and one parameter only (`@discount_code`), used three times:

```
SELECT
    @discount_code AS discount_code,
    sales_revenue,
    rsp_float,
    marketing_spend
    sales_revenue - marketing_spend AS roi_dollars,
    revenue_share,
    CAST( ((sales_revenue - marketing_spend) / marketing_spend) AS DECIMAL (5, 2) )
        AS roi,
    CAST( (sales_revenue / marketing_spend) AS DECIMAL (5, 2) )
        AS mroi
FROM
    (   SELECT
            sr.sales_revenue,
            kd.revenue_share_percentage / 100  AS rsp_float,
            kd.fixed_media_cost,
            sr.sales_revenue * kd.rsp_float AS revenue_share,
            kd.fixed_media_cost + (sr.sales_revenue * kd.rsp_float) 
                AS marketing_spend 
        FROM
            (   SELECT
                    CAST(SUM(total_price) AS UNSIGNED) AS sales_revenue
                FROM
                    shopify_orders
                WHERE
                    discount_code = @discount_code 
            ) AS sr
          CROSS JOIN
            kpi_data AS kd
        WHERE
            kd.CODE = @discount_code
    ) AS t ;
```